# Jenkins-Github Integration in different OS

Tags: jenkins

I have a windows machine where I have installed jenkins(master). Then I installed jenkins slave in cent os which is a SSH server. There is a github repository which I have checked out in that cent os machine. Now I wanted to configure a job from the master jenkins which is in window to perform git pull operation in the cent os. How can I do this? Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "**Restrict where this project can be run**" from Configure job option in jenkins 
[image]

you need to provide label name.